# Openpyxl rotating column headers

Tags: openpyxl

Openpyxl, is there a way to rotate column headers?
(please see image for example)

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can rotate column headers by rotating each cells. 
For this you need to use `Alignment` and set `text_rotation` to the angle you want. [Documentation here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.alignment.html).

Here is a quick example of how I did it in a project:
(`sheet` is your active sheet)

```py
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

headers = {
   1 : "Name",
   2 : "Version",
   3 : "Date"
}

for key in headers:
   cell = sheet.cell(row=1, column=key)
   cell.value = headers[key]
   cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', text_rotation=50)
```